# What is the reason of this alternation?

Tags: sanskrit

[image]

[image]

The second case is similiar to e-grade / zero-grade ablaut. 
Is it possible to find out the place of a stress here?
For use:
वसति vásati
वर्धति várdhati

Comment: Eventually you're going to have to read, like, a running text (be it a textbook or just a Wikipedia article) instead of just trying to guess everything based on random wiki tables. I mean this with kindness.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Do you think the textbook *Grundlagen der Elektronik* that I have here will do, or have you something specific in mind?

Comment: @Cairnarvon if somebody child ask his father "daddy, why the sky is blue"

What do you think his father will answer him? "read, son, read" or he will give his paternal opinion?

Comment: @Cairnarvon Is it your minus, am i right?

Comment: @fedor Not this time, actually. I only downvote questions when they're *trivially* researchable (i.e. by googling the most obvious thing and clicking the first link), and while I do think you need to pick up an introductory textbook at some point, this is not that.

Answer (score 2):

The first verb, वसति *vasati*, is considered an irregular verb, at least as for how its Passive base/stem is formed.

The second verb, वर्धति *vardhati*, is pretty regular: its root is वृध् *vṛdh* and the Passive is formed regularly with the suffix *-ya-*. The Present tense base/stem *vardha-* is also formed regularly: the root zero-grade vowel (*ṛ*) takes the first degree of strengthening called [*guṇa*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gu%E1%B9%87a#Sanskrit_grammar) (full-grade), namely *ṛ* > *ar*, and the suffix *-a-* is added. So you're right about the vowel alternation, in a way. As for Sanskrit stress, it's a rather complicated issue, not always possible to establish unanimously. Only note that the stress you cite in the question, *vasat**í***, belongs to the noun and the adjective, while for the verb [Wiktionary gives](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%B5%E0%A4%B8%E0%A4%A4%E0%A4%BF#Pronunciation_2) the stress on the root, *v**á**sati*.

Comment: It seems to me that the difference only in "a". If we delete it from vasati we get **usyate** because u is a semivowel (v before a vowel, u before a consonant) then we get **uṣyate** because of RUKI law "s after u always ṣ"

Comment: You are wright Thank you

Comment: @fedor - It's the other way round in Sanskrit: the Passive is _not_ derived from the Active Present, but both forms of the 1 conjugation verb are derived from the _root_ (both your verbs are of the 1st conj.). As a rule, in the Passive the root is present _as it is_, while in the Act. Pres. its vowel takes _guṇa_. When we look at _uṣyate_, we could think the root is _uṣ_, so the Act. Present stem should be _ōṣa_ (_u_ > _ō_ in guṇa degree) while actually the root is _vas_ and the Act. Present stem is _vasa_, that's why the verb is irregular. **Va** has always been in the root (< PIE *h₂wes).